# Find $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{P(B|A_n)}{P(F|A_n)}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

A bag has 3 coins in it: a fair coin, a coin biased in favor of heads such that heads is thrice as likely as tails, and a two-headed coin. One of these coins is drawn at random and tossed $n$ times. Let $F$ and $B$ denote the events that the chosen coin is fair, and biased. Assume that each of the 3 coins is equally likely to be drawn from the bag and that outcomes in different tosses of any coin are independent of each other.

let $A_n$ be the even that all $n$ tosses turn up heads.

What would be the procedure to find $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{P(B|A_n)}{P(F|A_n)}$

here is what i have.

Just take the limit of this as $n$ approaches infinity

$$\frac{\frac{(1/3)(3/4)^n}{(1/3)(3/4)^n+(1/3)(1/2)^n+(1/3)(1)^n}}{\frac{(1/3)(1/2)^n}{(1/3)(3/4)^n+(1/3)(1/2)^n+(1/3)(1)^n}}$$

If this is correct then ill attempt to proceed but I don't know how to take the limit of this.

Comment: Why is $T$ defined? To calculate $P(B\mid A_n)$ and $P(F\mid A_n)$, it might be useful to invoke Bayes' theorem/rule.

Comment: What do you think? Are you aware of [Baye's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes'_theorem)?

Comment: I don't think that the limit exists. But your working is correct. Simplify(cancel off some terms) the expression a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Baye's Theorem to obtain that \begin{align}P(B\mid A_n)&=\frac{P(A_n\mid B)P(B)}{P(A_n)}\\[0.3cm]P(F\mid A_n)&=\frac{P(A_n\mid F)P(F)}{P(A_n)}\end{align} Now, note that a lot of things get canceled out in this fraction, so that the calculations are much less involved than they seem. Recall that $P(B)=P(F)$ since each coin is equally likely to be chosen, so that the fraction reduces to $$\frac{P(B\mid A_n)}{P(F\mid A_n)}=\frac{P(A_n\mid B)}{P(A_n\mid F)}=\frac{(3/4)^n}{(1/2)^n}=\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n\to \infty$$ as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand this. The answer is that it just blows up to infinity?

Comment: @Mike Yes, that is what it does. Do not get mislead that it has to be bounded since both numerator and denominator are probabilities, i.e. between $0$ and $1$. The denominator vanishes at a much faster rate than the numerator and so the fraction (not the probabilities involved, be careful) indeed blows up! Your work was correct, but it is much simpler to notice that so many things, get cancelled out. Otherwise, what you did is perfectly correct!!